# MFC Feature Pack - How to add accelerators without deleting user's customization

Tags: mfc, mfc-feature-pack, accelerator

I want to add new accelerators to my MFC Feature Pack application. The problem is the app loads the accelerators already stored in the registry, thus disabling the new ones I've added. I know I could delete the Keyboard-# key in the registry, but that would delete any customization made to the accelerators by the user.

Is there any way to add the new accelerators to the ones posibly defined by the users?

Comment: I think your answer is in my reply to [this][1] thread.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1290752/why-is-cmfcmenubar-not-utilizing-the-accelerator-table/4186203#4186203

Comment: Good starting point: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20080523-00/?p=22203